# mod_rewrite: args lost

Tags: apache, mod-rewrite

I want to do a easy(?) rewriting.
Here is my .htaccess:

```
Options +FollowSymlinks  
RewriteEngine On  
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/batiments-[0-9]+/?$  
RewriteRule ^batiments-([0-9]+)/?$ a_batiments.php?e=$1
```

I want this rewriting: `http://xyz.com/batiments-123` ==> `http://xyz.com/a_batiments?e=123`

I obtain only the address: `http://xyz.com/a_batiments`, without the argument.
In the rewrite log, I see a line containing a split:

> 192.168.0.2 -(*very long line suppressed*) (3) split uri=a_batiments.php?e=123 -> uri=a_batiments.php, args=e=123

I understand the split is useful for the matching, but the args is never put back in the address. Why? What to do?

Answer (score 1):

Try adding the `[R]` [flag](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_rewrite.html#rewriteflags) to the RewriteRule. That way the rewrite results in a HTTP redirection being sent to the client.

Comment: Thank You ! It was not the solution, but your idea show me an ugly fault in my code. It was not mod_rewrite. Shame on me ! I spent 2 days on this problem... Once more thanks jdb